# Matplotlib: Change linewidth on all subplots

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I'm plotting a grid of subplots (6x2) with matplotlib (version 1.3.1) and Python 2.7.  I set up my figure and plot things in the subplots like this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=6, nrows=2, 
                         sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(30,5))

axes[0,0].plot(x, y)
axes[1,5].plot(z, a)
```

etc.

My question is this:  is there a way to change the line properties on all of these plots at once?  I could manually specify `axes[0,0].plot(x,y,'k',linewidth=2.0)` on each of the axes, but I thought there must be a way to do it for all 12 plots at once.

Cheers.

Comment: You can use `mpl.rc('lines', linewidth=2.0)`, not sure if I would prefer that over explicitly writing it in each call, though.

Comment: @cel Thanks.  That worked for linewidth, but why didn't ``mplr.rc('lines', color='black')`` work?

Comment: Interesting question. the docs claim that is should work. But it does not seem to work here either. http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/users/customizing.html#dynamic-rc-settings

Comment: See also: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4047

Comment: @cel The solution on github worked for me.

Comment: ended up with `plt.rc('lines', linewidth=2.0)`...

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2
```

This should dynamically change the default matplotlibrc configuration.

Edit: nevermind, already mentioned in the comments to your question.

Comment: Comment copied from above: Thanks. That worked for linewidth, but why didn't ``mplr.rc('lines', color='black')`` work?

Comment: The word `copied` makes it sound as if that was intentional. I guess I was just faster :)

Comment: @cel Sorry I meant my comment was copied from above. I wasn't accusing Andreas of copying.

Answer (score 1):

In my Jupyter notebook I do

```
%matplotlib inline
# plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')                # first, small enchancements, xlabels, ylabels, legand sizing...   
plt.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2               # Change linewidth of plots
# plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12, 8)        # Change the size of plots
```